# EEA Family Permit for a UK/EEA dual national residing in EEA state

Tags: uk-visa

This question is going to be quite specific, but to cut a long story short, i'm a UK-EEA national residing in the EEA state of which I hold citizenship - apparently rendering me unable to use the EEA FP entry route to bring over my non-EEA spouse (as I do not invoke free movement treaty rights).

If we insist on using this immigration pathway, the two options I have are a) renunciation of either citizenship or b) not declaring a citizenship on the EEA FP Home Office application. For curiosity's sake, I were to take option B, **could anyone tell me which of the three would most likely lead to a successful application**; declaring UK/undeclaring EEA, declaring EEA/undeclaring UK, declaring UK+EEA?

Further information:

1- I renewed my UK passport in July 2019 and, because I couldn't afford to be passportless for 1+ month, did not declare my extra citizenship on the online form. They sent me my new one without a problem, and i've never used it nor used the older one for several years.

2- I have used my EEA passport at various UK airport border e-gates, most recently July 2020.

So is there a database the home office can use to cross-reference my UK passport name against a list of all inbound passengers? Would they check if an EEA-only FP applicant also has a UK nationality?

I could really use a home office caseworker right now :)

Comment: Not declaring one of your nationalities is fraud.  You might not get caught, but if you are it's not going to end well.  You're either going to have to renounce your UK nationality or  bring your spouse using the regular immigration rules, with the minimum income and the high fees.  Renouncing your other nationality is not likely to help.

Comment: A general rule for dual nationals: while in one of the two countries, that country is **not** required to recognize the second citizenship and can treat you **soly** as their own citizen.